# Distance between two leaves in a DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Is there a way of computing the distance between two leaves in a [decision tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier).

By distance, I mean the number of nodes to go from one leaf to the other.

[image: graph]

For example, in this example graph:

```
distance(leaf1, leaf2) == 1
distance(leaf1, leaf3) == 3
distance(leaf1, leaf4) == 4
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example that relies on additional Python packages, namely [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) and [pydot](https://pypi.org/project/pydot/). For that reason, the solution is generously commented. The question was tagged with `scikit-learn` so the solution is presented in Python.

Some data and a generic `DecisionTreeClassifier`:

```python
# load example data and classifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# for determining distance
from sklearn import tree
import networkx as nx
import pydot

# load data and fit a DecisionTreeClassifier
X, y = load_wine(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3, random_state=42)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train);
```

This function transforms the fit `DecisionTreeClassifier` into a networkx undirected `MultiGraph` using [`tree.export_graphviz`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html#sklearn.tree.export_graphviz), [`pydot.graph_from_dot_data`](https://github.com/pydot/pydot/blob/109e85219b186e0e445090f803fdc7112e860f6f/pydot.py#L273-L282), [`nx.drawing.nx_pydot.from_pdyot`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.from_pydot.html), and [`nx.to_undirected`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.to_undirected.html).

```python
def dt_to_mg(clf):
    """convert a fit DecisionTreeClassifier to a Networkx undirected MultiGraph"""
    # export the classifier to a string DOT format
    dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf)
    # Use pydot to convert the dot data to a graph
    dot_graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)[0]
    # Import the graph data into Networkx 
    MG = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.from_pydot(dot_graph)
    # Convert the tree to an undirected Networkx Graph
    uMG = MG.to_undirected()
    return uMG

uMG = dt_to_mg(clf)
```

Use [`nx.shortest_path_length`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length) to find the distance between *any two nodes* in the tree.

```python
# get leaves
leaves = set(str(x) for x in clf.apply(X))
print(leaves)
{'10', '7', '9', '5', '3', '4'}

# find the distance for two leaves
print(nx.shortest_path_length(uMG, source='9', target='5'))
5

# undirected graph means this should also work
print(nx.shortest_path_length(uMG, source='5', target='9'))
5
```

`shortest_path_length` returns the number of edges between `source` and `target`. This is not the distance metric OP is requesting. I *think* the number of nodes between them would just be `n_edges - 1`.

```python
print(nx.shortest_path_length(uMG, source='5', target='9') - 1)
4
```

Or find distances for the all leaves and store them in a dictionary or some other useful object for downstream computation.

```python
from itertools import combinations
leaf_distance_edges = {}
leaf_distance_nodes = {}
for leaf1, leaf2 in combinations(leaves, 2):
    d = nx.shortest_path_length(uMG, source=leaf1, target=leaf2)
    leaf_distance_edges[(leaf1, leaf2)] = d
    leaf_distance_nodes[(leaf1, leaf2)] = d - 1 

leaf_distance_nodes
{('4', '9'): 5,
 ('4', '5'): 2,
 ('4', '10'): 5,
 ('4', '7'): 4,
 ('4', '3'): 1,
 ('9', '5'): 4,
 ('9', '10'): 1,
 ('9', '7'): 2,
 ('9', '3'): 5,
 ('5', '10'): 4,
 ('5', '7'): 3,
 ('5', '3'): 2,
 ('10', '7'): 2,
 ('10', '3'): 5,
 ('7', '3'): 4}
```